# .htaccess password protect with visibility

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the directory structure

```
folder
  ↳file1(public access)
  ↳file2(require password)
```

When I put the following in the .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "asdf"
AuthUserFile path/to/.htpasswd
<Files file2>
  require user asdf
</Files>
```

A non-logged in view shows this structure:

```
folder
  ↳file1(public access)
```

How do I provide the non logged in user visibility to `file2` so that they know that the file is in fact there, but may have to log in?

Comment: Perhaps you want [`IndexOptions ShowForbidden`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html)?

Comment: You can't, not with a simple browseable directory. To get INTO the directory you need to provide the password in order to see what's in there to start with. You'll have to provide a script (e.g. php) to list the files in the protected dir, and put that script somewhere OUTSIDE of `file2`, with protected links pointing INTO the directory.

Comment: @bishop  Yes.  Work well enough for basic file structure of the server.  Just want to know that the file is there, and if it needs to be protected ask for basic auth.  post answer for credit!

Comment: Another option is, you can use a custom `ErrorDocument 500` page with some info in it, if/once access is denied, which is what will be triggered on error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- post example and I will try it out.

Comment: Just place this `ErrorDocument 401 error401.htm` in your `.htaccess` file and create a page called `error401.htm` with anything you want inside it. That, being in the root of your server. Use something like `ErrorDocument 401/folder/error401.htm` if placed in a different folder. @chrisFrisina - I made a mistake earlier, it's not `500` it's `401`. 500 is for script error. It could also be `403` depending how you set it up. The complete list of ErrorDocument(s) are 400 - Bad request, 401 - Authorization Required, 403 - Forbidden directory, 404 - Page not found, 500 - Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1):

In this simple case, I believe you can employ [`IndexOptions ShowForbidden`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

If you get more complicated (like an auth covered directory or you want to show some forbidden but hide the rest), you'll have to resort to other methods (eg, generate your own index then show it, like in @Fred-ii- answer).

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't know about this till now. And thanks for the mention.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to an already given answer (a good option), you can place this in your `.htaccess` file

```
ErrorDocument 401 error401.htm
```

and create a page called `error401.htm` with anything you want inside it.

That, being in the root of your server.

Use something like:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /folder/error401.htm
```

if placed in a different folder.

It could also be `403` depending how you set it up.

The complete list of ErrorDocument(s) are:

1. 400 - Bad request
2. 401 - Authorization Required
3. 403 - Forbidden directory
4. 404 - Page not found
5. 500 - Internal Server Error

Of course, you can use `.php` as the preferred file extension and I'm leaning more towards using a `403` which is for `Forbidden directory`

**Footnotes:**

In some cases, you may need to use a full `http://` call:

```
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.example.com/error401.htm
```